# how to read a csv file in python while there are spaces in one object type column

Tags: python, csv, python-import, importerror

I have a large dataframe which has 33 columns. one column [ UDF20] has object type as below :
[image]

I've read the data with :
**df_TL= pd.read_csv('CYMIS.csv',skiprows=2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True)**

but when i use 
**df_TL['UDF20'].isnull().any()**
it's not able to recognise any null in the attached column and it gives me false as a result while you can see it has 639 null rows! 
I've been told to use pd.read_fwf but not sure how to write the syntax properly !

if the sample of data helps, here is a df_TL.head():

```
RG_Code    End_Date Pfolio_Code   Trans       Cost  Proceeds        Units  \
0  gh  31/12/2019      CCAS    OS-SAL    9992.37   10000.0    9892.1752   
1  gh  31/12/2019      CCAS    OS-PUR   50000.00       NaN   49455.9841   
2  gh  31/12/2019      CCAS    OS-PUR   10000.00       NaN    9890.2185   
3  gh  31/12/2019      CCAS    OS-SAL   39953.78   40000.0   39553.0505   
4  gh  31/12/2019      CCAS    OS-PUR  190000.00       NaN  187839.8418   


 Trans_ID Contract_Date  Entry_Date          ...           \
0   3040950    08/01/2019  09/01/2019          ...            
1   3041570    09/01/2019  10/01/2019          ...            
2   3042896    11/01/2019  14/01/2019          ...            
3   3044063    15/01/2019  16/01/2019          ...            
4   3046230    18/01/2019  21/01/2019          ...     


  External_code 2 Rate:Base_to_Nat                 UDF13  \
0  AU60ggg00759                      1.0                         
1  AU60ggg00759                      1.0                         
2  AU60ggg00759                      1.0                         
3  AU60ggg00759                      1.0                         
4  AU60ggg00759                      1.0    


             UDF20 Broker_Code  External_cO1                 Sedol  \
0  UNLISTED TRUST - 1      INTRNL  *WCSH                                
1  UNLISTED TRUST - 2      INTRNL  *WCSH                                
2  UNLISTED TRUST - 3      INTRNL  *WCSH                                
3  UNLISTED TRUST - 4      INTRNL  *WCSH                                
4  UNLISTED TRUST - 5      INTRNL  *WCSH     


      ISIN             BB_Ticker          SCD_Sec_Type  
0                                              UNIT TRUST            
1                                              UNIT TRUST            
2                                              UNIT TRUST            
3                                              UNIT TRUST            
4                                              UNIT TRUST            

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`


Can anyone help please?
```

Comment: if you want someone to help use ```read_fwf```, then you need to provide a sample-in text format-  of your data to test his code agianst. Otherwise we only can help you with samples from official docs

Comment: providing the head of data would be helpful ?

Comment: It's okay, Just few rows would be enough instead of the screenshot.

Comment: hope it helps ! looking forward to hearing from you